# How can I have set with sequence in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have the following `SET` in MySQL:

```
SET('winter2001', 'fall2001', 'winter2002', 'fall2002')
```

MySQL considers the values as strings and winter2001 is greater than fall2002 because as character w is after f

How can I set the assumption that winter2001 is less than fall2002?

Comment: You want to use `enum`s:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html.

Comment: Hi I used enum but the result still is the same

Answer (score 1):

Sort your data on:

```
CONCAT(RIGHT(date_field,4), IF(LEFT(date_field, CHAR_LENGTH(date_field) - 4) = 'winter', 'Q4, IF(etc))
```

Comment: I'm sure OP also wants the query to know that fall2001 comes after summer2001.

Comment: Ok, your edit would actually solve that... nice one!